# c++, how do I copy a vector into a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I figured the following code would work, Here's an abridged version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    int xCoordMovement, yCoordMovement;
    int rows, cols;
    char point = '*';

    std::cout << "enter number of rows";
    std::cin >> rows;
    cols = rows;

    std::vector<std::vector<char>> grid(rows, std::vector<char>(cols, '0'));
    std::vector<char> flattenedGrid;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
            std::cout << grid[x][y];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "input for x coord: ";
    std::cin >> xCoordMovement;
    std::cout << "input for y coord: ";
    std::cin >> yCoordMovement;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
            flattenedGrid.push_back(grid[x][y]);

    flattenedGrid[((cols * yCoordMovement) - (rows - xCoordMovement)) - 1] = point;

    std::cout << flattenedGrid.size() << std::endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < flattenedGrid.size(); i++)
        std::cout << flattenedGrid[i];

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
           for (int i = 0; i < flattenedGrid.size(); i++)
                grid[x][y] = flattenedGrid[i];


    for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
            std::cout << grid[x][y];
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

However it does not seem to change the values of the grid, it should now have a value that is a star at one of it's coordinates, but alas, all grid contains is it's original values.

relevant output:

```
00000 
00000 
00000 
00000 
00000
```

desired output:

```
00000
000*0
00000
00000
00000
```

Here is the bit I was hoping would assign the values of my vector into my vector of vectors:

```
for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        for (int i = 0; i < flattenedGrid.size(); i++)
            grid[x][y] = flattenedGrid[i];
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Be sure to read about the [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  If at all possible, your code should have a main() and be standalone compilable, such as in an [online compiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/).  Anything that's not central to your question should be removed.  You should be able to show the output that you get, and explain the output that you wanted.  *(Saying things like "it should now have a value that's a star at one of it's coordinates" when there is no `*` in your code isn't actionable.)*

Comment: `grid[x][y] = flattenedGrid[y]` is just overwriting every row with the first `cols` entries of `flattenedGrid`.  Also, your linear index `((cols * yCoordMovement) - (rows - xCoordMovement)) - 1` looks very suspicious -- you should check that it's calculating the value you expect.  It's not clear why you need to flatten the whole grid just to do this one operation.  Why not set the value directly into `grid`?

Comment: I put up my whole program. I tried figuring out how to user cin coordinates for x and y, essentially allowing them to pick points on a coordinate plane. I could not think of a way of doing it without first flattening the grid and adjusting the index for the entered xCoord and yCoord.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of changes you have to make to the code:

- **First, when you assign `point` to an element of `flattenedGrid`**

*Change:*

```
 flattenedGrid[((cols * yCoordMovement) - (rows - xCoordMovement)) - 1] = point;
```

*to:*

```
flattenedGrid[(yCoordMovement) + (rows * xCoordMovement)] = point;
```

- **Second, when you refill `grid` with elements of `flattenedGrid`**

*Change:*

```
for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
    for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)
        for (int i = 0; i < flattenedGrid.size(); i++)
             grid[x][y] = flattenedGrid[i];
```

*to:*

```
for (int x = 0; x < rows; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < cols; y++)          
                grid[x][y] = flattenedGrid[rows * x + y];
```

Comment: Thank you! this is definitely superior to what I had.